# Complex Object vs Subjunctive with wish

Tags: subjunctives

We wish you **did** more good things daily. 
We wish you **to do** more good things daily.

Is there any difference in meaning? When should we use each one if we have difference?

Comment: The first might be a complaint, rebuke, or reminder, and the second might be simply a request with no implication of previous or current failure, but equally they might mean the same thing.

Comment: _We wish you did X_ - it would be a good thing if you did so. _We wish you to do X_ is a (fairly polite) command.

Comment: "We wish you would/can/could do more good things daily" seems more natural as spoken English than "to do" (depending on the exact situation and whether it's more of an order, a request, a hope, or literal genie/fairy-based wishing); "We wish you to do..." sounds very old-fashioned to me, but maybe others consider it OK.

Comment: @StuartF - I was thinking of the (more likely) variant _I want you to do X_ as a politely-expressed command, for example allotting duties to a volunteer.

Comment: There's no subjunctive here.  "to do" is an infinitive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While both sentences can be used to indirectly ask someone to do more good things daily, the literal meanings are not the same.

Your first sentence means something like, "*We **think it's unfortunate** you don't do more good things daily.*" It directly expresses a feeling or opinion. Depending on the context, the listener may or may not infer a request to do more good things daily, or they may just understand it as a lament.

Your second sentence means something like, "*We **want** you to do more good things daily.*" It directly expresses a desire. The listener would probably understand this as a request, but again, it could just be an expression of a desire.